# No entra en el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo la siguiente ruta

```
Route::resource('mail', 'MailController');
```

A la que llamo en el siguiente formulario:

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            @if (Session::has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
            @endif
            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Contáctenos</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('mail.store')}}">... 
</form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

con su correspondiente formrequest:

```
    <?php

namespace libreir\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MailFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'texto' => 'string|required'
        ];
    }
}
```

y debería entrar en el método store especificado en la ruta del formulario pero por alguna anomalía que desconozco me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: page expired]

¿Alguna explicación del por qué y una solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese problema ocurre porque no has incluído el token CSRF en el formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('mail.store')}}">
   @csrf
   ...
</form>
```

O en versiones anteriores a Laravel 5.6:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('mail.store')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Me sale el mismo error, ¿quizá tengo que limpiar el caché o algo?

Comment: Tal vez, aunque nunca he tenido que hacerlo. ¿Verificaste que el campo aparezca en el formulario?

Comment: Si te refieres a esto: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="snxgCctogstv8jypdQ3xZ9kYhxKDacxb6fGFLhdg">si, sin embargo me sigue saliendo el error

Comment: Entonces todo está bien, debería funcionar. Tendrías que hacer un poco de depuración en el request y cuando se realiza la validación del token.

Comment: Ya está, ha funcionado, he leido por ahí que podría ser de las cookies, no se como va el asunto en chrome pues no lo uso mucho, pero prové a cambiar de navegador, (me pasé a firefox) y ya funciona, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Recuerda responder mi pregunta de tu anterior pregunta (la de orWhere)